# Robovm mac issue, Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, libgdx, robovm

I have been trying to set up my mac environment for a while now but am having trouble importing my project using gradle. I've been following all the instructions and I have read through both of these forums (http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=14168, http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=13419), but I still cannot figure out what the problem is.

When I try to build the gradle project I am receiving this error:

> com/github/jtakakura/gradle/plugins/robovm/RoboVMPlugin : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

From what I have read that means there is something wrong with the JDK I am using. I have downloaded and re-downloaded JDK 7 and made sure that eclipse is using it [image]

I have my compiler setting to 1.7, I have also tried it at 1.6 and it still does not work.

I have the JAVA_HOME path set as follows:

```
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_67.jdk/Contents/Home
```

and this is what I get for the Java version:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_67"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)
```

Looking at the two threads that I linked, I think I addressed most of the issues yet I still see that error. I am relatively new to using MACs so maybe there is a glaring omission on my part.

Also, I was just trying to run a plain robovm iOS project and I recieved this error:

```
 Plug-in org.robovm.eclipse.ui was unable to load class org.robovm.eclipse.internal.NewCocoaTouchProjectWizard.
 An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.robovm.eclipse.ui
```

Not sure what it means.

Note: I have seen a few StackOverflow topics relating to this but I feel like I have addressed the issues presented in them and yet still have this error.

Edit: As I mentioned in my note. I have already addressed the JDK issue which my post elaborates on. To the best of my knowledge I have J2SE 7 enabled yet I still have the error. So I was wondering if I could have missed something.

Comment: `Unsupported major.minor version 51.0` I don't think it's your Java installation... That's the version number of the project or one of its dependencies.

Comment: According to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10382929/unsupported-major-minor-version-51-0 , the issue has to do with the jdk.

Comment: Oh, it's not the installation but the version in the project... It's probably in one of the gradle build files.

Comment: I hadn't checked the gradle build files thoroughly. I'll give them a look and see if they are causing the issue.

Comment: Yeah, there might be a reference to version 51 in there somewhere.

Comment: Turns out it was not the gradle file. It has to do with the Jdk. I'll have to keep playing around with it.